# How can I change the input field value when using the Rails Simple Form gem, with a JS onclick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, simple-form

I have set up a JS function in my Rails app that fetches the current location of a user. I want the coordinates that are returned to go into a field in my Rails simple form on the click of a button. I tried using `innerHTML` and `value` to change the element but this doesn't work with the simple form gem. Any ideas of a way to make his work?

Here is the JS code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("coordinates");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.value = position.coords.latitude + 
    ", " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

And my simple form view:

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Current location</button>
<input id="coordinates"></input>

<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>

<%= f.input :start_point, input_html: { id: 'coordinates' } %>
<%= f.input :restaurant_location %>
<%= f.input :customer_location %>
<%= f.input :fee %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You are using id `coordinates` more than once.

Comment: *facepalm* - you're right... thanks a lot for spotting!